# How to make Bootstrap dropdown NOT hide on clicking react components displayed within dropdown?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, redux, react-bootstrap

I have a react component (say 'x') that is wrapped within OverlayTrigger ( triggers on click and appears at the bottom) of React-Bootstrap (example [React Bootstrap overlay](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#tooltips%22React%20Bootstrap%20Overlay%22) => Search for OverlayTrigger ). I'm using Bootstrap Dropdown to display 'x' React Components. ( example [Bootstrap dropdown](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_dropdown-menu&stacked=h))

As expected the overlay must appear on clicking the x component but bootstrap drop-down closes at the same time. Due to which the overlay is appearing at window's top left position and dropdown hides.

Is there any way to make overlay click not affect the drop-down to hide but if a user clicks anywhere outside the dropdown it should close?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that open class is added on the dropdown div (id=dropDownOpen) when the dropdown button is clicked. Thus I used a hack of adding class open to the div when li item (i.e. my react component) is clicked.

This is my onClick function triggered when any li item is clicked :

```
const keepDropDownOpen = () => {
  window.$('#dropDownOpen').addClass('open');
}
```